# Python - dictionary assertion failure

Tags: python, dictionary

When i print the type of my object i get the following

```
print(type(rankings[0]))
```

> ```
> <class 'dict'>
> ```

but when i try to make the following asserting it fails

```
assert type(rankings[0]) is dict , "not a dictionary"
```

> ---
>
> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        29 
>        30 print(type(rankings[0]))
>   ---> 31 assert type(rankings[0]) is dict , "not a dictionary"
>        32 
>        33
>
> AssertionError: not a dictionary

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Probably it's just a class that is called `dict` but isn't the built-in dict. Not exactly expected but not unheard of either. However, without having all the details this isn't answerable without guessing.

Comment: What does `print(dict)` give you? I suspect you've shadowed `dict`. I.e., you've done something like `dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}`

Comment: this is how i am initializing my dictionary: dictx = {}

Comment: @AhmadDebbas that **is not my question**. I said, what happens when you `print(dict)`

Comment: this is what happens:

{'price': '$$', 'numrevs': '549', 'stars': '4.0', 'name': 'Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken'} @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @AhmadDebbas yes, just as I suspected, you **shadowed** the built-in name for the `dict` type.

Comment: oh, i don't understand. How should i have created the dictionary? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @AhmadDebbas **don't call it `dict`**, because now when you check `type(another_dict) is dict` that variable, `dict` doesn't refer to the *type* dict, i.e. `dict != <class 'dict'>`

Comment: ohh, yeah now i got you. I restarted the kernel of my python notebook and didn't use any variable named dict. it worked. Thanks for your help! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1):

To check if rankings[0] is an instance of dict you should use:

```
isinstance(rankings[0], dict)
```

That way you also catch subclasses of dict. Not sure why 'is dict' isn't working for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't answer why the 'is dict' isn't working, but perhaps it will solve the problem.

There is a comment to the question for more info.

Answer (score -1):

The built-in name "dict" was overshadowed by a variable i have used.